# How do you make Javascript add the width of one element to another's height?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, variables

This is my first website. I'm having fun with it, but there are some things I can't seem to figure out.
I have an image, and I have four smaller images that look like portions of the main image. I have set it up so that the smaller images fade in as the main image fades out, and they fly off to the side of the screen. To position the small images correctly, I set their position to that of the main image, and I'm trying to get the bottom two images to have half the main images width added to their height. For some reason, my javascript/jQuery isn't working though. I've messed around with the code, and found when I take out the variable "width" the code works, so I think it must be a problem with the way I declared or called the variable.

Here's some of my code:

HTML:

```
<img class="fmsmall smallbutton" src="Images/FacilityMaintenance 2.png" />

<img class="lightsmall smallbutton" src="Images/Lighting.png" />

<img class="pssmall smallbutton" src="Images/PowerSweeping.png" />

<img class="landsmall smallbutton" src="Images/Landscaping.png" />
```

CSS:

```
#logoBig {
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -20%;
width: 40%;
top: 15%;

}

.pssmall {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -20%;
    width: 20%;
    top: 15%;
    z-index: 100;
}

.landsmall {
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    width: 20%;
    top: 15%;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

javascript/jQuery:

```
function categoryClick( beforeClickButton, 
                        afterClickButton, 
                        subcategoryMenu,
                        subcategoryHeader, 
                        leftClickBefore, 
                        topClickBefore, 
                        leftClickAfter, 
                        topClickAfter,
                        low
                        ){

    $(beforeClickButton).click(function()
        {

        $(afterClickButton).fadeIn("fast");



/*Here's the code that isn't working*/
        var width = $("#logobig").width();

        if(low = true){
            $(afterClickButton).animate(  {
                top: "+=" + (width / 2) + "px"
            });
        }



        $(".categoryButton").hide();

        $("#logoBig").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#selectCategory").delay(250).fadeOut("slow");

        $(afterClickButton).delay(250).animate({
            left: leftClickBefore,
            top: topClickBefore
            }, "slow");

        $(subcategoryHeader).delay(250).fadeIn("slow")
        $(subcategoryMenu).delay(1000).fadeIn("slow");
        $("#accordion").fadeIn("slow");

        $(afterClickButton).delay(500).one("click", function(){

            $(this).animate({
                left: leftClickAfter,
                top: topClickAfter
            }, "slow");

            $(subcategoryHeader).delay(250).fadeOut("slow");
            $(".categoryButton").show();
            $("#logoBig").delay(600).fadeIn("slow");
            $("#selectCategory").delay(500).fadeIn("slow");
            $(afterClickButton).delay(250).fadeOut("fast");
            $(subcategoryMenu).fadeOut("slow");

        });

        var icons = {
                    header: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-e",
                    activeHeader: "ui-icon-circle-arrow-s"
                    };
        $(subcategoryMenu).accordion({ collapsible: true,
                                    header: ".menuItem",
                                    heightStyle: "content",
                                    active: false,
                                    icons: icons
                                    });  

    });




}


categoryClick(          ".facilityMaintenance", 
                        ".fmsmall", 
                        ".fmMenu", 
                        ".fmHeader",
                        "-=30%", 
                        "-=25%", 
                        "+=30%", 
                        "+=25%",
                        false
                        );


categoryClick(          ".lighting", 
                        ".lightsmall", 
                        ".lightMenu",
                        ".lightHeader", 
                        "-=50%", 
                        "-=20%", 
                        "+=50%", 
                        "+=20%",
                        false
                        );


categoryClick(          ".powerSweeping", 
                        ".pssmall", 
                        ".psMenu", 
                        ".psHeader",
                        "-=32%", 
                        "-=55%", 
                        "+=32%", 
                        "+=55%",
                        true
                        );


categoryClick(          ".landscaping", 
                        ".landsmall", 
                        ".landMenu", 
                        ".landHeader",
                        "-=50%", 
                        "-=55%", 
                        "+=50%",  
                        "+=55%",
                        true
                        );
```

The actual site is on my company's server, so I just put a copy on a free server to post here. Here's a link. The error messages don't show up on the actual site.

http://www.pcsinternal.net76.net/newcontractportal/go.html

Regarding the error messages, I have set a link to a password protect PHP script on line one, but it isn't linking properly. How might I fix that?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: My initial thought is that you probably want to put the execution code inside a `$(document).ready(function() { ... code here ... });` type thing - you'll not be able to retrieve the width of the image until it's loaded... but unless I'm missing something, you don't actually **have** and image with an id of 'logobig' so `$("#logobig").width()` is going to fall over.

Comment: That's only part of the code. I included both $(document).ready(function() {code}); and the image with the id "logobig" in the actual file. I just didn't want to post the entire code, because it might take a while to find the code I'm specifically talking about. I probably should have at least included the code with the image, but you should be able to view the code with your browser functions when you're on the link to the website.

Comment: With the error messages, you're attempting to include the file 'password_protect.php' using an URL which won't work - you need to have the file on the same server and include using the filepath. *unless the server has `allow_url_include` "on" which it doesn't - hence the error (not really surprising, it's a bit of a security no no)